# jQuery toggle search button

Tags: javascript, jquery, togglebutton

I use old javascript code to flip my search button from search to searching in my forms as follows

```
<div id="search_clickable"> <input class="search" type="submit" value="search" onClick="javascript:flipSearchButton();"></div>
<div id="search_unclickable" class="hidden"><img src="/assets/img/searching.png" alt=""></div>
```

My javascript function is

```
function flipSearchButton()

{
   document.getElementById('search_clickable').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('search_unclickable').style.display = 'block';
}
```

How to I achieve this with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function flipSearchButton(){
    $('#search_clickable').hide(); // or - $('#search_clickable').toggle();
    $('#search_unclickable').show(); // or - $('#search_unclickable').toggle();
}
```

**And stop using inline javascript:**

```
$('.search').click(flipSearchButton);
```

Note that your search button is of type `submit` (?!) so it will submit the form, You probably want to change the type to `button` or return false from the callback:

```
function flipSearchButton(){
    $('#search_clickable').hide();
    $('#search_unclickable').show();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: that makes sense. If I have more than one instance of search buttons on the page will that work?  or do I need to change the div id to classes?

Comment: @aa1. That depends on what you want. My code will add this `click` event for class with the `search class`. If you want to customize it you can, change ids classes or what ever you want...

Comment: this works in terms of replacing the search button with my searching gif image but doesn't submit the form, nothing happens

Comment: @aa1. o.k. if you want the submit to occur, don't write `return false;` simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

include jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

then:

```
function flipSearchButton()

{
   $('#search_clickable').hide();
   $('#search_unclickable').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i thought something like this:

```
$("#search_clickable").click(function() {
  $("#search_clickable").hide();
  $("#search_unclickable").show();
});
```

if you wanna toggle this element, use toggle() instead of hide() and show().

Comment: Probably no point in using toggle() as you hide the div containing the button and therefore can't be clicked again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider to use fade effect to improve user experience

```
function flipSearchButton() 
{
  $('#search_unclickable').fadeIn('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete
  });
  $('#search_clickable').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a separate function:

```
$("input[type=submit").click(function() {
   $("#search_clickable").hide();
   $("#search_unclickable").show();
});
```

Or use the id/class of the submit button if you want to on a specific button:

```
$(".search").click(function() {
   $("#search_clickable").hide();
   $("#search_unclickable").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below URL for toggle Div.

Check below Working Demos 
 
As per your question : [Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekbhalani/wsMnf/6/)  
As per my        opinion : [Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekbhalani/wsMnf/8/)

Thanks